# gnome-sound-applet no longer available in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, indicator, applet

In 14.04 I had the `gnome-sound-applet` in my `stalonetray` but the applet is no longer available in 16.04.     Is there a replacement?     Thanks.

Comment: did you install this yourself?

Comment: Does it fall under the indicator-sound package under some magical new alias? http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/sound/indicator-sound

Comment: I can't recall whether I'd installed `gnome-sound applet` under 14.04, or whether it came with the installation.   I have `indicator-sound` installed correctly, but don't know how to use it to give me an applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [pa-applet](https://github.com/fernandotcl/pa-applet). [My fork](https://github.com/kynan/pa-applet) contains a [fix](https://github.com/kynan/pa-applet/commit/451f68353ffad9c4cf988a022cb92864655fd7f1) for a [compilation issue](https://github.com/fernandotcl/pa-applet/issues/11) and allows using a custom maximum volume via e.g.

```
./configure MAX_VOLUME=200.0
```

An alternative is [volnoti](https://github.com/davidbrazdil/volnoti).

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions @hynan.     I tried to install pa-applet, but hit an error that's documented on the thread  https://github.com/fernandotcl/pa-applet/issues/11 .     One person claims to have edited the Makefile, and managed to do the install, but I didn't know how to make the edit.    Odd that the last complaint was in Dec 2014.   Also, you obviously didnt have this problem, or got around it somehow?      I also downloaded volnoti, but it doesn't appear that it will work in my stalone tray, so I didn't try installing it.

Comment: There's are several forks of pa-applet that contain the fix for that issue, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @LeoSimon Done!

Comment: It's not easy to see whether mute is on or off.    Instead of the usual 'x', the little blue sound waves disappear when mute is on.  But the sound waves are very faint, so it's a bit hard to see.   Is there a configuration option to add an 'x' when mute is on?   Or better yet, increase the color intensity of the sound-wave icon   Thanks!

Comment: @LeoSimon Not that I'm aware of, but I'm not the author. It's open source so you can make further changes yourself.